# Here is code where I have to display information through various buttons. The issue is that when I click one button, the other buttons display info

Tags: reactjs, button, axios, onclick

I used axios to retrieve the data and I tried to add toggle switches, but I wasn't able to figure it out.
**Prettier 2.7.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAgCU4BDMGAGn2HwFcBnOAZRhPnwF98AzHCdfAB0QOUuWGCoGbHnz0YATwA2cACY8+AgOTzlagLSQs0BDHpbJlqcdkkAHqgj0N-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-CdyJw4+XgUZ4NimwD4nC5QqBc6b4GKOz4AAZAhQpriB060EowEgQ2YHkn6wKYIk4EFlO2HYdOsT4PEcAKA+4HlKgqifrh7xVLuAD6ZB-hwx6xFhZGZMkyQjue64qhh-ENsJqH4Mec6SZky6rqJ06Adet5xPED5PjwnLcvuJAfiKPKoKIXb-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-Ou8QbG4LWpt-AJfCwrKAkPQ+hQHAahqDHojb6ZcAl4H5dIKb5sgIw6CoI7zvV6sFwtzvxuP5XZ+B5x6qEnkgLYgsnYkFQLEC4UR+APxAM6P4Md8QABUSCVAPk-auQYXYAEkoBvFgEwMAo8RbtiISwPQndGAcA4EAA)

```bash
--parser babel
```

**Input:**

```
function ButtonClick(){
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const fetchData = () => {
  axios.get("https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies")
      .then(response => {
        setUsers(response.data)
      })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.bond_actor}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
      <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Directors</Button>
      {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>    
      <div>
      <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Songs</Button>
      {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
      <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Movie Years</Button>
      {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>      
    </div>

  )
}

export default ButtonClick
```

**Output:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import axios from "axios";

function ButtonClick() {
  const Button = styled.button`
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  `;

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setUsers(response.data);
      });
  };
  const Actors = () => {};
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.bond_actor}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Directors</Button>
        {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Songs</Button>
        {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Movie Years</Button>
        {users.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {users.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```

I believe that I may have to index somehow a way to make sure the button I press is the only button being pressed and not the only one. I just don't know how to implement it with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same state for all the buttons, which is why you get the data in all places.

I just added a type to differentiate which button I clicked; based on that; the data is displayed on UI.

Below is the simple logic that I applied.

```
const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setUsers({ [type]: response.data });
      });
  };
```

I'm assigning data based on the state based on the type. The state data can be rendered like `users.band.map`. I am attaching the sandbox for reference.

[image: Edit muddy-cdn-q08wiz]